# Created a page with onenote ink beta api, it says "Content not yet available"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

[Edited - added the problematic XML]

Created a page with [Ink API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2017/07/07/onenote-ink-beta-apis/), got the 'OK' return from the server.

But if I check form the OneNote site, it says

> "Content not yet available: Sorry, it looks like this page was added
>   from another computer and hasn't synced yet. Click here or press enter
>   to reload this page."

Without Ink data it works fine, and the Ink xml data is exact copy of the other page.

Was there any change in the API?

PS> Please try with this XML, which I got from the GET command with 'includeInkML=true' parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inkml:ink xmlns:emma="http://www.w3.org/2003/04/emma" xmlns:msink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ink/2010/main" xmlns:inkml="http://www.w3.org/2003/InkML">
  <inkml:definitions>
    <inkml:context xml:id="ctxCoordinatesOnly">
      <inkml:inkSource xml:id="inkSrcCoordinatesOnly">
        <inkml:traceFormat>
          <inkml:channel name="X" type="integer" max="32767" units="himetric" />
          <inkml:channel name="Y" type="integer" max="32767" units="himetric" />
        </inkml:traceFormat>
        <inkml:channelProperties>
          <inkml:channelProperty channel="X" name="resolution" value="1" units="1/himetric" />
          <inkml:channelProperty channel="Y" name="resolution" value="1" units="1/himetric" />
        </inkml:channelProperties>
      </inkml:inkSource>
    </inkml:context>
    <inkml:brush xml:id="{6c84b3ca-9760-44d5-ae07-277d913fbd8b}{40}">
      <inkml:brushProperty name="width" value="100" units="himetric" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="height" value="100" units="himetric" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="color" value="#404040" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="transparency" value="0" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="tip" value="ellipse" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="rasterOp" value="noOperation" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="ignorePressure" value="false" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="antiAliased" value="true" />
      <inkml:brushProperty name="fitToCurve" value="true" />
    </inkml:brush>
  </inkml:definitions>
  <inkml:traceGroup>
    <inkml:trace xml:id="{6c84b3ca-9760-44d5-ae07-277d913fbd8b}{41}" contextRef="#ctxCoordinatesOnly" brushRef="#{6c84b3ca-9760-44d5-ae07-277d913fbd8b}{40}">6217 13042, 6164 13042, 6138 13069, 6111 13095, 6111 13122, 5952 13122, 5661 12884, 5423 12646, 5265 12407, 5212 12143, 5212 11905, 5582 11614, 5820 11561, 6455 11534, 7116 11534, 7619 11799, 7989 12090, 8069 12354, 8095 12778, 8095 13228, 7963 13571, 7804 13810, 7513 14021, 7249 14074, 6958 14101, 6587 14101, 6323 13968, 6190 13862, 6138 13783, 6111 13651, 6111 13545, 6217 13439, 6534 13439, 7196 13519, 7513 13730, 7698 13942, 7698 14127, 7751 14365, 7646 14603, 7513 14735, 7196 14788, 6905 14841, 6667 14841, 6508 14788, 6481 14603, 6455 13915, 6772 13466, 7354 13122, 8307 12963, 9153 12963, 9656 13228, 9921 13598, 10026 14153, 10026 14603, 9868 15000, 9656 15238, 8995 15423, 8519 15423, 8069 15212, 7804 14974, 7540 14471, 7381 13730, 7381 12989, 7646 12143, 8254 11455, 9127 10952, 10397 10608, 11138 10503, 11376 10476, 11455 10476, 11481 10529, 11481 10608, 11429 10688, 11429 10714, 11349 10714, 11296 10661, 11296 10608, 11296 10397, 11296 9947, 11349 9127, 11720 8677, 12407 8439, 13016 8386, 13228 8386, 13360 8492, 13413 8704, 13439 8810, 13439 8862, 13466 8889, 13466 8836, 13466 8730, 13466 8598, 13360 7857, 13280 7222, 13201 6614, 13280 6058, 13704 5688, 14312 5582, 15026 5529, 15423 5661, 15582 5794, 15608 5847, 15608 5873, 15635 5873, 15661 5873, 15794 5873, 15926 5820, 16005 5794, 16085 5661, 16217 5370, 16429 5000, 16931 4788, 17487 4683, 17884 4683, 18122 4815, 18122 4868, 18122 4921, 18122 4947, 18148 5000, 18175 5000, 18280 4974, 18413 4894, 18466 4788, 18466 4444, 18466 4180, 18466 3942, 18757 3810, 19312 3836, 19841 4153, 20079 4392, 20132 4577, 20132 4683, 20132 4735, 20132 4762, 20185 4735, 20265 4683, 20344 4630, 20450 4524, 20476 4392, 20635 3968, 20952 3704, 21349 3651, 21534 3598, 21587 3545, 21614 3545, 21614 3492, 21614 3466</inkml:trace>
    <inkml:trace xml:id="{6c84b3ca-9760-44d5-ae07-277d913fbd8b}{57}" contextRef="#ctxCoordinatesOnly" brushRef="#{6c84b3ca-9760-44d5-ae07-277d913fbd8b}{40}">10873 39233</inkml:trace>
    <inkml:trace xml:id="{6c84b3ca-9760-44d5-ae07-277d913fbd8b}{62}" contextRef="#ctxCoordinatesOnly" brushRef="#{6c84b3ca-9760-44d5-ae07-277d913fbd8b}{40}">27513 38651, 27487 38651, 27434 38651, 27328 38677, 27196 38704, 27090 38730, 26931 38730, 26693 38757, 26323 38757, 25979 38757, 25370 38757, 24788 38677, 24180 38598, 23757 38519, 23466 38466, 23042 38413, 22725 38360, 22513 38333, 22407 38307, 22355 38307, 22302 38307, 22275 38307</inkml:trace>
  </inkml:traceGroup>
</inkml:ink>
```

Comment: I'm not sure Microsoft Graph support these APIs just yet (it isn't anywhere in the documentation).

Comment: If you can provide us with the value of the X-CorrelationId and Timestamp of the response of your request, we can look into this.

Comment: I captured the packet, and I can see followings from the response header.
- client-request-id: eb1dc3bd-094a-4c17-934f-f9433c51c7b5
- createdDateTime":"2018-01-25T20:33:12.83047Z

Comment: I've seen the Content not yet available message too many times to count. It indicates your ink post is malformed. I recommend trying to get the syntax correct based on the example in the page you highlighted above before trying anything more ambitious. On macosx I use CocoaRestClient to manually try API commands, Fiddler works for windows.

Comment: I copied the exact XML from that BetaAPI page, and it works... Frankly I have no idea what's wrong with my XML. Only the difference is my XML is 'ctxCoordinatesOnly' and the structure seems legit, of course it's from the existing page returned by GET api. Maybe I need another 3rd party library for Ink data validation and make up... :(

Comment: If you specify RasterOperation, you will need to either specify maskPen or copyPen.

Comment: Thanks @Manjusha, so it seems the XML returned is not enough and I better have good Ink library and reconstruct the XML again?... thanks...

Comment: In the future, we will add some validations for creating a page with Ink, so that it will be useful to know exactly what went wrong. Thanks for your feedback and sorry about the trouble.

Comment: thanks again for explanation.

Comment: Have you tried downloading/cloning https://github.com/Microsoft/InkMLjs ?
 You can use dragdrop.html and a text file with ink commands to validate the ink data (or at least see if it works).

Comment: I believe you already tried, my XML works fine with that (InkMLjs). It shows properly. Any recommendations for the InkML library for parse/validation/creation (C#) ?

Comment: Just looked at your ink xml data the only error is value="noOperation" if you change this to "copyPen" as suggested by Manjusha your page is created correctly for me.

Comment: Thanks @codeye. What I'm trying to do is to restore the content data, so from the last GET result I need to create 'proper' xml. To do that, I think I need a special library to check such points, as you analyzed. I'm searching for such libraries but no luck.

Comment: Hi Locke. In my user case I do something similar (except I take the ink data and translate it to another page - stretch/shrink etc) and you should be able to just extract the data and essentially cut and paste everything from <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> to </inkml:ink> and it will reproduce the ink in the new page. My problems arose when I was trying to create ink from a webpage using a modified version of InkMLjs - sorted now.

Comment: One thing the ink API doesn't like is two brushes with the identical name (even if they have identical characteristics). When merging ink from two pages this had me stumped for ages.

Comment: @codeye, sorry I don't get your point. that XML has only 1 brush item. And your suggestion for 'extracting', it is already extracted. The whole story here is very simple. You draw anything with ink to a page and save it, and you get that page data and ink, and you create a page with that data and you can not create it.

Comment: Given the only issue with your example page have you tried just searching your XML and replacing noOperation with copyPen (I'm using OneNote on iPads and Android tablets and they don't seem to return noOperation as a brush option). Are you using a windows tablet, I think in Jorge's write up he suggests you need to turn off handwriting recognition?

Comment: Ok got  it. Thanks @codeye.  I wrote that with just mouse on the Web Browser.